# log_min_duration_statement setting is ignored

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, logs, performance, postgresql-performance

I am running `Postgresql 9.1` on Ubuntu. Exact Postgresql version is `9.1+129ubuntu1` as my package manager shows.

I have 2 databases that are actively in use and they are used from a remote server.

I wish to log queries that have a long execution time. So I set following parameters in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` file

```
log_min_duration_statement = 10000
log_statement = 'mod'
```

so Postgresql will log queries that takes longer than 10 seconds.

But when I `reload` the postgres configuration, Postgresql begins to log every query that fits `log_statement` value. That I set  duration to 100 seconds to be sure

```
log_min_duration_statement = 100000
```

But Postgresql keep logging every query that fits `log_statement` value, regardless of `log_min_duration_statement` value.

Setting `log_statement` to `none` seemed to stop logging.

Is there something that I missed about the configuration?

Comment: The thing is that you log the union of the two sets, not the intersection of it.  I am not aware if it can be done as you'd like.

Comment: So, should I disable (comment out) `log_statement` so `log_min_duration_statement` should work?

Comment: If you simply want to log all long-running statements (be it a `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or some DDL), then yes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You were close. Your last idea is actually the way to go:

```
log_statement = none
log_min_duration_statement = 10000
```

Then no statement will be logged, except those running longer than 10 seconds - including the query string itself. Logging may have seemed to stop because 10 seconds is a high threshold. I am using 2 seconds normally, but YMMV.

This related answer on SO has more:

- [Cannot get log_min_duration_statement to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425131/939860)

Comment: Let me add that the default for `log_statement` is `none`, so not setting it or setting to `none` has the same effect.