# Another "log_min_duration_statement is ignored" question

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.2, logs, postgresql-performance

Following the recommendations in [`log_min_duration_statement` setting is ignored](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62842/log-min-duration-statement-setting-is-ignored) I set these two values and then reloaded.

```
log_min_duration_statement = 2000
log_statement = 'none'
```

However, I'm still getting lots of sub-second BINDLOG, BEGINLOG and PARSELOG entries in the log file.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the connections are coming from JDBC for example, I have found that sometimes it takes a while for the connections to all be recycled, and thus pick up the changes to l_m_d_s.

Comment: Since those terms do not occur anywhere in the source code, it is difficult to believe that they get produced by the system unbidden.  Please give a verbatim example of the  entire message.

Answer (score 1):

Check individual users and / or dbs for settings that override server settings for logging:

```
smarlowe=# alter user smarlowe set log_statement='all';
ALTER ROLE
smarlowe=# alter database smarlowe set log_statement='all';
ALTER DATABASE
smarlowe=# \drds
                   List of settings
   Role   | Database |            Settings
----------+----------+---------------------------------
 smarlowe |          | log_statement=all
          | smarlowe | auto_explain.log_min_duration=1+
          |          | log_statement=all
```